# Convention: if (!foo) vs unless (foo). And while (!foo) vs until (foo)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby along with RoR and noticed that instead of using

```
if !foo
```

ruby provides

```
unless foo
```

In addition, instead of:

```
while !foo
```

we have

```
until foo
```

Coming from C++/Java, it seems to just confuse me when I read unless/until. Does it seem like people who program a lot in ruby conventionally use unless/until instead of just negating if/while?

Is this something I should just get used to or do you see a lot of variance on the subject?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using `unless condition` instead of `if !condition` is common and idiomatic.

```
unless foo
  # ...
end
```

It's especially common to use as a post condition:

```
# Bad
raise "Not Found" if !file_exists?(file_name)

# Good
raise "Not Found" unless file_exists?(file_name)
```

When in doubt, follow [ruby-style-guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

Comment: just force of habit, It has been edited.

Answer (score 5):

From the syntax section of the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#syntax):

> Favor unless over if for negative conditions (or control flow ||).

```
# bad
do_something if !some_condition

# bad
do_something if not some_condition

# good
do_something unless some_condition

# another good option
some_condition || do_something
```

And

> Favor until over while for negative conditions.

```
# bad
do_something while !some_condition

# good
do_something until some_condition
```